# Get text of an element based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul class="vm_cat">
  <li><a class="mainlevel" href="/">MAIN LEVEL 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="sublevel" href="/">sub 1 a</a></li>
  <li><a class="sublevel" href="/">sub 1 b</a></li>
  <li><a class="sublevel" href="/">sub 1 c</a></li>
  <li><a class="sublevel" href="/">sub 1 d</a></li>
  <li><a class="mainlevel" href="" id="active">MAIN LEVEL 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="hide sublevel" href="/">sub 2 a</a></li>
  <li><a class="hide sublevel" href="/">sub 2 b</a></li>
  <li><a class="hide sublevel" href="/">sub 2 c</a></li>
  <li><a class="mainlevel" href="/" id="active1">MAIN LEVEL 3</a></li>
  <li><a class="hide sublevel" href="/">sub 3 a</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to know how to remove the class `hide` from `sublevel` onclick on `#active`. I dont want to remove `hide` from `sublevel` which is next to `#active1`.

Comment: please include relevant code

Comment: I am working on that. got problem with ul and li tags

Comment: why are they in the same ul is sub suppose to be under main?

Comment: please check if this is want you want and what else is needed?http://jsfiddle.net/Loye43f2/

Comment: can you provide me the code how can I find the sublevel using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.mainlevel').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Loye43f2/1/)

Use class to select the sibling ul using `.siblings()` and toggle on click using `.toggle()`

[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Loye43f2/2/)

Updated demo until 3rd level list